# Disable directadmin access for one domain, setup another location to manage

Tags: directadmin

I just set up a DirectAdmin server. What I'd like to accomplish is disabling http://example.com:2222 on certain websites. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but according this [link](https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=56958) it seems you can't do that!

> If you point the domain to a dedicated IP then you can block access to 2222 on the IP with firewall.
>
> There are no other options.

anyway if we assume you could do this other users also can access your directadmin with your IP address like this :

**`1.2.3.4:2222`**

I really don't know why you wanna do this but maybe changing your server port is good option..